# validation for specific cell in DataGridView 1

Tags: vb.net

How to do validation for **DataGridView** row details whether is already exists or not when pass the value form **Textbox** into **DataGridView**?

This is my function: `argAccount` & `argPortfolio` are Textbox value

```
Function fnValidateAccountPortfolio(ByVal argAccount As String, ByVal 
argPortfolio As String) As Boolean
    Try
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Form1.DataGridView1.Rows
            If Not row.IsNewRow Then
                MessageBox.Show(row.Cells(0).Value.ToString & "  Is Already
                Exists", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        Exit Function
    End Try
End Function

Private Sub BtnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As
System.EventArgs)
Handles BtnSave.Click
  If fnValidateAccountPortfolio(txtAccount.Text, txtPortfolio.Text) = False
  Then
    MessageBox.Show("Successfully Saved", "Save", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
    MessageBoxIcon.Information)
  End If
end sub
```

Comment: Have you tried this link already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976739/finding-text-from-the-datagrid-view-in-vb-net

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976739/finding-text-from-the-datagrid-view-in-vb-net) I provided is this what you are looking for?

```
Function fnValidateAccountPortfolio(ByVal argAccount As String, ByVal argPortfolio As String) As Boolean

    Dim found As Boolean = False

    For Each Row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In Row.Cells
            If Not (cell.Value Is Nothing) Then
               If (CStr(cell.Value).Trim() = argAccount OR CStr(cell.Value).Trim() = argPortfolio)  Then
                  MessageBox.Show(cell.Value.ToString()) ' You could show the value here just to validate but remove it later.
                  found = True
                  Exit For
               End If
            End If

        Next
        If (found) Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Return found
End Function
```

So, you will be calling this function like

```
if (fnValidateAccountPortfolio("1001","PortfolioHere")) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Entry exist already in the DataGrid!!!")
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Successfully Saved", "Save", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
End if
```

Comment: It's debugging at     If (CStr(cell.Value).Trim() = argAccount Or CStr(cell.Value).Trim() = argPortfolio) Then

Comment: What error is coming out if any? Or what is the message again if any?

Comment: NullReferenceException was unhandlled Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Check my changes @ParamesveryArumugam I tested if cell is nothing or NULL.

Comment: no error but it doesn't show that the new entry is exist or not..kindly help on this

Comment: Did you my follow my Validation? like if (fnValidateAccountPortfolio(txtAccoun.Text,txtPortfolio.Text)) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Entry exist already in the DataGrid!!!")
End if

Comment: If (fnValidateAccountPortfolio(txtAccount.Text, txtPortfolio.Text)) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Entry exist already in the DataGrid!!!")
        End If
        MessageBox.Show("Successfully Saved", "Save", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)                                         It shows as already exist but the exist value also added into DataGridView..

Comment: Did you use ELSE it looks like you did not! Check my code change and change your code accordingly.

Comment: it is possible to show specific exist value (which cell value is already entered) in messagebox? any idea?

Comment: Sorry..I don't know that where I should use if else statement..I also not that much familiar with vb.net..if you don't mind can u help me?

Comment: thanks again..if you don't mind, I have posted one more question which is "Pass the edited textbox value into DataGridView", can you help me on this?