# Select the row in data grid view

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a data grid view with 4 columns in it.
I simply want to do that, When user writes the value in a textbox and click on the button it'll highlight the row with that value.

I've tried this code but it didn't work

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView2.Rows
    If row.Cells(0).Value.ToString = "'" & txtSearch2.Text & "'" Then

        Dim index As Integer = row.Index

        DataGridView2.Rows(row.Index).Selected = True

    End If
Next
```

It's a visual basic program.
Any help is welcome.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you enclose the textbox text inside single quotes? Are these quotes present in the grid cell?

Comment: No these are not

Comment: @Steve i removed the single quotes but still getting this error                                   {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code, this will change all matched cells backgound color to yellow:

```
DataGridView2.ClearSelection()

For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView2.Rows
    For each cell As DataGridViewCell in row.Cells

        If cell.Value Is Nothing Then Continue For

        If CStr(cell.Value).Tolower.Contains(txtSearch2.Text.Tolower) Then

            cell.Selected = True

            'Yellow background When matched
            cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow

        End If
    Next

Next
```

You can find more useful informations in this similar question:

- [Finding text from the datagrid view in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976739/finding-text-from-the-datagrid-view-in-vb-net)

Comment: there is an error in this place                                                                                  StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase

Comment: Not working :( Still getting the error of null reference

Comment: try adding `If cell.Value Is Nothing Then Continue For` check my answer update